# How to convert existing Angular 14 project to Angular Universal 14 with .netCore Web API integration

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular14upgrade, .net-core-angular

I Want to convert the existing **(ASP .net core 16 application with Angular 14)** project to an **ASP .net core application with Angular Universal 14**

I know how ASP .net core application work with Angular 14 when we create a .net core project using an angular template, But I want to know the steps of how **angular universal work with a .net core project**

I am working on a .net core project using an angular template

[image]

This is the Project.csproj

[image]

this is Program.cs

[image]

CORS Policy Error when login from SSR Application

[image]

I have added **<BuildServerSideRenderer>true</BuildServerSideRenderer>** but not working and also added UseSpa and UseAngularCliServer middleware to the program.cs but I think something I have missed.

Some points about the problem which I have faced

1. How to write code in a program.cs how to set middleware in the **app.spa, spa.UseAngularCliServer**
2. How to run **angular universal through the .net core project**
3. How APIs will work, how to integrate angular universal with .net core API, currently I am facing CORS policy Errors

**I want to run my existing angular universal project with the .net core web API**

Thanks in advance, your support will Appreciate

Comment: The code samples you're using are already 3 years old. What .NET version are you using? [Here's](https://medium.com/@pieterjandeclippel/server-side-rendering-in-asp-net-core-angular-2022-version-7aaed8157976) the most recent guide to setup asp.net core + angular universal. There's already .NET 7 targetting releases of the packages too. [Here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.Templates/tree/master/src/content/ServerSideRendering) are some dotnet templates with ssr out of the box

Comment: Also `SupplyData` was replaced with [the following](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.Templates/blob/master/src/content/ServerSideRendering/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.ServerSideRendering/Program.cs#L16)